# React Native v0.72 debugging: Browser exited with error:, inbalid url, missing http/https protocol

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes, react-native-debugger, flipper

I tried opening the debugger on the iOS simulator and got this error as soon as I clicked it:

```
info Opening flipper://null/Hermesdebuggerrn?device=React%20Native...
error Browser exited with error:, invalid url, missing http/https protocol
```

Neither React-Native Debugger or an in-browser debugging panel would come up. Any idea on what's causing this?

Comment: I encountered the same issue.

Comment: Was it resolved?